# Vue memory leak: each time v-if value is changed, more memory is needed

Tags: vue.js, memory-leaks

I have many components X which themselves contain many more components. X all have a v-if=“show”. Show is triggered by the user for each X and can be triggered as many times as the user pleases. Now I figured that each time the user triggers “show” (twice) the application needs more memory. I don’t really understand why, because to my understanding the component X and all underlying components should be completely removed from memory as soon as “show” is false?

Can someone tell me why this might happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This actually seems to turn out as my mistake. I took the snapshots right after triggering the components over and over again. If you wait a couple of seconds and then take the snapshot, Vue takes care of it and memory is back to normal.